# CASL is not working properly in Vue Production Mode

Tags: vue.js, casl

I have defined some rules for specific roles, they all are working fine. But when I build vue project in production mode, all the rules gives false. Details are here below:

I have this file `ability.js`, which is giving me rules:

```
export const getRules = (role, userId) => {
     const { can, cannot, rules } = AbilityBuilder.extract()
     switch(role) {
          case 'TENANT_ADMIN':
                   can('manage', 'all')
                   break
          case 'TENANT_AGENT': 
                   can('view', 'ConversationView')
                   break
          case 'TENANT_AGENT_LIMITED': 
                   can('view', 'ConversationView', { userId: userId })
                   break
     }
     return rules
}
```

I'm updating rules like this in App.vue (all values are valid)

```
this.$ability.update(getRules(role, userId))
```

I'm checking permissions using below code.

```
class ConversationView {
    constructor(props) {
        Object.assign(this, props)
    }
}

this.$can('view', new ConversationView({ userId: Id }))
```

Now, when I run this code in local/development mode. It is working fine (giving me true where it needs to), but when I generate a production build it is not working as expected (always gives me false)

Development Build Command:

```
vue-cli-service build --mode local --modern
```

Development Build .env.local

```
VUE_APP_STAGE=development
NODE_ENV=development
```

Production Build Command:

```
vue-cli-service build --mode prod --modern
```

Production Build .env.prod

```
VUE_APP_STAGE=production
NODE_ENV=production
```

Let me know why this is happening.

**Replicated the steps here.**

Follow below link to view running and expected version:
[LINK 01](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/s4h1u1b9h9a2m/vue-casl-example/tree/master/)
Output:

```
Checking for '1' => true 
Checking for 1 => false 
Checking for '2' => false
```

Clone the same project in your local, or download it from [github [2](https://github.com/s4h1u1b9h9a2m/vue-casl-example)
After running, we're getting this output:

```
Checking for '1' => false 
Checking for 1 => false 
Checking for '2' => false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. Because of minification for production build code was not working as expected. Had to define `modelName` function to return proper name.

Follow the link for more info.

https://stalniy.github.io/casl/abilities/2017/07/21/check-abilities.html#instance-checks