# After build Vue.js project the CASL library not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, casl

I try check ability by class instance:

```
<Can
 I="delete"
 :a="createHomeTask(item.teacher.id)"
>
</Can>
```

Where ability description:

```
if (role === 'ROLE_teacher') {
  can('delete', 'HomeTask', { teacher: user.id });
}
```

Where createHomeTask:

```
class HomeTask {
  constructor(teacherId) {
    this.teacher = teacherId;
  }
}

export default function createHomeTask(teacherId) {
  return new HomeTask(teacherId);
}
```

Before building the project, everything works fine, but after the build, this functionality does not work.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is caused by Vue minifying code when building, so CASL doesn't work properly. This question might be also related to your problem: [CASL is not working properly in Vue Production Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57677510/casl-is-not-working-properly-in-vue-production-mode). (However, the link to the docs in the answer is outdated for some reason, but I have this page saved)

In official docs (at least earlier) solving this problem was covered:

> By default, CASL is looking for modelName attribute on constructor of the passed object (and fallbacks to constructor name if that is blank).

```ts
class Post {
  constructor({ title, published }) {
    this.title = title
    this.published = published
  }
}
```

> **Important**: if you use minification for production builds, it will minify class names as well and this example won’t work. For such cases, you can define static modelName attribute on a class.

> In this example, ability will check rules for Post and not for Article:

```js
class Article {
  static get modelName() {
    return 'Post'
  }

  constructor({ title, published }) {
    this.title = title
    this.published = published
  }
}
```

I suggest you try doing the following:

```js
class HomeTask {
  static get modelName() {
    return 'HomeTask'
  }
  constructor(teacherId) {
    this.teacher = teacherId;
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you.